# how to print everything from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to do this question for class that is really confusing me, I can't seem to figure it out. They give me this code and say that I need to do something to make it print all of the flowers in the dictionary instead of printing just one. Here is the code that is provided, which just prints one of the flowers.

```
def build_floralArrangement(size, **flowers):  # **flowers is a list of key-value pairs to add to the dictionary.

    """Build a dictionary containing customer requests for flowers."""

    arrangement = {}

    arrangement['size'] = size

    for key, value in flowers.items():

        arrangement[key] = value

        return arrangement

myArrangement = build_floralArrangement('large', flower1 = 'tulips', flower2='red roses', flower3='white carnations')

print(myArrangement)
```

Comment: Unindent `return arrangement` so it happens *after* the loop instead of inside of it.  Right now you're returning before the loop is done so you only ever get one flower.

Comment: You can also simplify the whole thing by just putting `**flowers` straight into the dict rather than doing it one by one in a loop, though.  The entire function body can be one line: `return {'size': size, **flowers}`

Comment: FWIW, it's not really clear what this code is supposed to do at all: basically it just takes a dict and copies it in a needlessly convoluted ways. *How much* are you supposed to change? The function could be done in 1-3 lines, and there is definitely no need for a loop.

Comment: Note that "flowers is a list of key-value pairs" is plain wrong – it's already a `dict`. You don't even have to copy it, since it is created just for this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def build_floralArrangement(size, **flowers):  # **flowers is a list of key-value pairs to add to the dictionary.

    """Build a dictionary containing customer requests for flowers."""

    arrangement = {}

    arrangement['size'] = size

    for key, value in flowers.items():

        arrangement[key] = value

    return arrangement

myArrangement = build_floralArrangement('large', flower1 = 'tulips', flower2='red roses', flower3='white carnations')

print(myArrangement)
```

Output:

```
{'size': 'large', 'flower1': 'tulips', 'flower2': 'red roses', 'flower3': 'white carnations'}
```

All I did was move your `return` statement out of your `for` loop.

Answer (score -1):

unindent `return arrangement`
because this way you are returning a single key-value object:

```
for key, value in flowers.items():

    arrangement[key] = value

return arrangement
```

If you want to show only the flowers I would do the following (as advice):

```
myArrangement = build_floralArrangement('large', flower = 'tulips', flower='red roses', flower='white carnations')
```

and then:

```
for key, value in flowers.items():

    arrangement[key] += value

return arrangement
```

And then to show the flowers:

```
print(arrangement.get('flowers'))
```

In this way you have a simpler dictionary and that can be used for more things, I hope it helps you